# Android how to show DatePicker in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-datepicker

I am new on Android Fragments and I want to know that how can I show or implement `DatePicker` in simple `Fragment`and not a `FragmentActivity`.

For example my class name is:

```
public class FragmentAddCard extends Fragment {
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code to show your efforts and then ask for help.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your button click call the DateFragment like this

```
   dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

        }
    });
```

Here is the code snippet for DateFragment

```
  public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
        }
        public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            dob.setText(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
            }

    }
```

Comment: in the Date Fragment class. I couldnt resolve dob. Please help

Comment: @Sagar Devanga It is TextView to show the selected Date

Comment: i know but i have both things in different classes and how can i pass the reference of dob or attach a listener. Because it is not allowing me create a constructor with the listener and asking me to use the default constructor.

Comment: see i have two fragment in an activity both having this datefragment..but sometimes it works on one fragment and sometimes second...

Comment: `TextView dob= (TextView)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.dob);` should fix the error when running it inside a activity

Comment: @DonChakkappan thanks dear. Its working fine can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779110/android-spinner-doesnt-showing-last-selected-item/

Comment: `SelectDateFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state` exception occurred.

Comment: Nice answer based on this [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker). Let's keep in mind that we can choose the style of the `DatePickerDialog` calling e.g. `return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, this, yy, mm, dd);`

Comment: fragmentManager is deprecated

Answer (score 11):

This is other example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()); // Get current date

// Create the DatePickerDialog instance
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    R.style.AppBlackTheme, datePickerListener,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                                        cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePicker.setCancelable(false);
            datePicker.setTitle("Select the date");
datePicker.show();

// Listener
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        String year1 = String.valueOf(selectedYear);
        String month1 = String.valueOf(selectedMonth + 1);
        String day1 = String.valueOf(selectedDay);
        TextView tvDt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvDt.setText(day1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + year1);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all i can say that,Selected answer is working fine.it is a good approach. But if you want to use [MaterailDatePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) with Fragment. I found a solution. Try following for Set DatePicker in Fragment.

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
}
```

DatePickerFragment

```
package com.wdullaer.datetimepickerexample;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DatePickerFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private TextView dateTextView;
    private CheckBox modeDarkDate;
    private CheckBox modeCustomAccentDate;
    private CheckBox vibrateDate;
    private CheckBox dismissDate;
    private CheckBox titleDate;
    private CheckBox showYearFirst;
    private CheckBox showVersion2;
    private CheckBox limitSelectableDays;
    private CheckBox highlightDays;

    public DatePickerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.datepicker_layout, container, false);

        // Find our View instances
        dateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
        Button dateButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.date_button);
        modeDarkDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.mode_dark_date);
        modeCustomAccentDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.mode_custom_accent_date);
        vibrateDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.vibrate_date);
        dismissDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.dismiss_date);
        titleDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.title_date);
        showYearFirst = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.show_year_first);
        showVersion2 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.show_version_2);
        limitSelectableDays = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.limit_dates);
        highlightDays = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.highlight_dates);

        // Show a datepicker when the dateButton is clicked
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        DatePickerFragment.this,
                        now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                );
                dpd.setThemeDark(modeDarkDate.isChecked());
                dpd.vibrate(vibrateDate.isChecked());
                dpd.dismissOnPause(dismissDate.isChecked());
                dpd.showYearPickerFirst(showYearFirst.isChecked());
                dpd.setVersion(showVersion2.isChecked() ? DatePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_2 : DatePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_1);
                if (modeCustomAccentDate.isChecked()) {
                    dpd.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"));
                }
                if (titleDate.isChecked()) {
                    dpd.setTitle("DatePicker Title");
                }
                if (highlightDays.isChecked()) {
                    Calendar date1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    date2.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1);
                    Calendar date3 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    date3.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
                    Calendar[] days = {date1, date2, date3};
                    dpd.setHighlightedDays(days);
                }
                if (limitSelectableDays.isChecked()) {
                    Calendar[] days = new Calendar[13];
                    for (int i = -6; i < 7; i++) {
                        Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
                        day.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, i * 2);
                        days[i + 6] = day;
                    }
                    dpd.setSelectableDays(days);
                }
                dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DatePickerDialog dpd = (DatePickerDialog) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Datepickerdialog");
        if(dpd != null) dpd.setOnDateSetListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year;
        dateTextView.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  button_name.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                         String years=""+year;
                         String months=""+(monthOfYear+1);
                         String days=""+dayOfMonth;
                         if(monthOfYear>=0 && monthOfYear<9){
                             months="0"+(monthOfYear+1);
                         }
                         if(dayOfMonth>0 && dayOfMonth<10){
                             days="0"+dayOfMonth;

                         }
                         race_date.setText(months+"/"+days+"/"+years);
                     }
                 }, now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                datePickerDialog.setMinDate(now);
                datePickerDialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Datepicker");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360251/edit) your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made. [ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360251/8371915)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an approach which covers SDK'S versions as well. As the app might brake if for example constructor for SDK 24 is used and app itself is run on SDK 21. The solution below should work both on Fragments and on Activities:

```
//Initialize datePickerDialog in any onClickEvent (Fro example on certain button click) and show it's contents
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = createDatePickerDialog(datePickerDialogOnDateSetListener, activity, null);
datePickerDialog.show();

// Method to create Universal DatePickerDialog no matter the SDK (current supports only SDK 19+)
public DatePickerDialog createUniversalDatePickerDialog(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerDialogOnDateSetListener, Context context, Calendar calendar) {
        if (calendar == null) {
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        }
        final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.DatePickerDialogTheme, datePickerDialogOnDateSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.DatePickerDialogLatestTheme, datePickerDialogOnDateSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(true);
        } else {
            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, datePickerDialogOnDateSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }

        return datePickerDialog;
    }

// the callback received when the user "chooses" the date in the dialog
public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerDialogOnDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
       public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            date.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(selectedDate.getTime()));
        }
    };
```